# MySQL New Record insert with unique ID with the increment of 1

Tags: mysql

we are making the help center which has the following database fields

[image: TicketDatabase]

now as we have set the main TicketID to auto increment from 1 that is OK but we want if possible our other column CLID to store the unique ID with the increment of 1

example TID001 then TID002 and so on so how can we do that

DB image attached FYR

Comment: It is not recommended if you have two columns storing the same unique ID. Why don't you process the CLID using PHP code whenever needed?

Comment: Can you please edit the question and show your (relevant) code? Please use the clipboard to paste it as text, don't take pictures of it. Answers can't possibly be a tutorial that explains how to get auto-incremented IDs and update database columns in every database library and framework that exists.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález as we need to fix the thing for now is a MySQL problem as we want to show the ticket id as TID001 then TID002 and so on is it possible to store it like this in the database if yes then how 

its the same like whenever new ticket is created its ID is stored in the CLID column like this TID001 TID002 which looks kind of good when the user has to check his progress on ticket so ticket will be shown in format TID001